# How to delete a key from a B+ Tree such that this key exist in an internal node and has another copy from it in a leaf node?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

All the online tutorials said that you shall delete the copy in the leaf node then make the other copy in the internal node = (the successor of that key) , my question is that what guarantees for us that this successor wasn't existing in an internal node before replacing our key copy in the internal node by it , because if such a thing happened we will have the value of that key (successor) existing more than one time in more than one internal node.

I found no answers for that in the online tutorials

Comment: *"All the online tutorials"*: please reference and quote what you are referring to.

Comment: *"you shall delete the copy in the leaf node then make the other copy in the internal node"*: unless nodes need to merge, there is no need to do anything with "the other copy" -- although I am not sure what you refer to. Please give concrete examples of what you mean (i.e. an actual B tree and an actual key to delete, and the problem you see with it).

Comment: I 'm taking about deleting from a B+ Tree , as you know all the keys of the internal nodes has another copy in a leaf node , so when deleting a key which exists in an internal node you shall also delete the other copy of it which is located in the leaf node , the tutorials says that  1) delete the copy in the leaf  2) make the copy in the internal = successor (which will be existing in a leaf node ) .  now the successor exists in an internal node , so what guarantees for us that it wasn't existing in an internal node before doing so which may make us have 2 copies of it in 2 internal nodes

Comment: Which tutorial are you referring to? There is actually no need to update that key in the internal node. Just removing the *real* key in the leaf node is enough. But please reference the tutorial you are referring to.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/b-plus-tree-deletion   , this is one of the tutorials but all the tutorials say the same

Comment: I don't see that in that tutorial. Which phrase are you referring to?

Comment: in deleting 25 , as you can see that it was deleted from both the internal node and the leaf node

Comment: Yes, I see it does that (although it is not a deletion, but an **update**), but it is not described in the procedure at the top, and it is not necessary.

Comment: my question was that for a key K that exists in an internal node , why always it's successor S doesn't have a copy in an internal node . from about an hour I discovered that the reason is in the technique of insertion of the keys in a leaf node of the B+ Tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting to your question, it is a misconception to regard the keys of the internal nodes as actual *data* keys. They are merely index-keys, and don't really need to belong to the tree's data set, although it is common to have them updated to reflect the minimum key that is present in its corresponding subtree.

In comments you refer to [this documentation](https://www.javatpoint.com/b-plus-tree-deletion) and to the example of the deletion of the key 25:

[image]

But note that the update of the key in a parent node is not strictly necessary. The same documentation stated at the start:

> - STEP 1 Find leaf L containing (key,pointer) entry to delete
> - STEP 2 Remove entry from L
> - STEP 2a If L meets the "half full" criteria, then we're done.

The case where key 25 is removed, fits the condition of step 2a, i.e. after it has been removed from the leaf node, "we're done". This is actually true. In this case the *update* of the key in ancestor node(s) is optional.

Now to your main question:

> what guarantees for us that this successor wasn't existing in an internal node before replacing our key copy in the internal node by it

The keys that exist in internal nodes are always a lower bound for the keys in the next subtree below it. Unless that subtree will undergo shifts or merges due to the deletion, the least key in that subtree will become a key that previously was *not* the least key in that same subtree. In the example, 28 was not the least key in the subtree because that least key in that subtree was 25. So we can be sure 28 is not present in an internal node.

It is a different story if the leaf node happened to **only** have 25 as key, but then we get into a shift or merge operation, which will bring updates to multiple keys.